# Conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint. How to solve this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

I catch this `GenericADOException` exception but some unexpected exception comes again when I do `genRep.Update(userW)`. How can I fix this problem? This is my code:

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser(long? UserID)
{
    GenericRepositoryV2 genRep ;
    if (!SecurityService.IsLoggedIn(Session))
    {
        return SecurityService.LoginAndRedirect(Request);
    }

    try
    {
        genRep = new GenericRepositoryV2();
        genRep.StartTransaction();
        User user = genRep.GetById<User>(UserID);
        if (user == null)
        {
            found = false;
        }
        else
        {
            UserWrapper userW = genRep.GetByIdUser(UserID);                    
            genRep.Remove<User>(userW);
            genRep.EndTransaction();            
        }
    }
    catch (GenericADOException gae)
    {
        if (gae.InnerException.Message.IndexOf("REFERENCE constraint") != -1)
        {
            genRep = new GenericRepositoryV2();
            genRep.StartTransaction();
            UserWrapper userW = genRep.GetByIdUser(Convert.ToInt64(UserID));
            userW.Status = UserStatus.PendingDelete;
            genRep.Update(userW);
            genRep.Flush();
            genRep.EndTransaction();
        }

        //_log.Error("An error has occured while deleting the user.");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error("Unexpected, unhandled exception: ", e);
    }
    return RedirectToAction(viewAllUsers);
}
```

I hope someone help me!
thank you in advance

**update 1:**

Exception:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was caught
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]
  Source=NHibernate
  SqlString=SQL not available
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher.DoExecuteBatch(IDbCommand ps)
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteBatchWithTiming(IDbCommand ps)
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteBatch()
       at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
       at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
       at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
       at OmanERP.Persistence.GenericRepositoryV2.EndTransaction() in e:\OmanERP\OmanERP\Persistence\GenericRepositoryV2.cs:line 583
       at OmanERP.Controllers.UserController.DeleteUser(Nullable`1 UserID) in e:\OmanERP\OmanERP\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 144
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       HResult=-2146232060
       Message=The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK48A70817829118FC". The conflict occurred in database "OmanERP_Harpreet", table "dbo.Invoices", column 'GeneratedByID'.
The statement has been terminated.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=16
       LineNumber=1
       Number=547
       Procedure=""
       Server=192.168.1.20
       State=0
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteBatchRPCCommand()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandSet.ExecuteNonQuery()
            at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientSqlCommandSet.ExecuteNonQuery()
            at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher.DoExecuteBatch(IDbCommand ps)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: you can have an other try-catch block inside your catch block. if this is not what you mean, you have to be more specific about what exactly goes wrong the second time (what exception, for example)

Comment: yeah i tried this already but it display the same exception.so what would i do?

Comment: What does your .StartTransaction() do? Since you call StartTransaction, then you get the exception, and then call StartTransaction again... What exception do you get the second time?

Comment: show the whole exception you get (and make sure we know which line number is where in your code), and if you tried what i said, then show that code instead. do this by editing the question, not writing everything in comments.

Comment: @hoijoi i put the exception above.

Comment: @ErikSundström 2nd time again i caught this exception.     StartTransaction() is a method for begin_transaction.

Comment: You need to check your FK constraint that the delete statement is conflicting with. Check FK48A70817829118FC in the database. UserId is referenced as a FK in another table and this says that you cannot remove the User before removing the referenced rows in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by that error, your repository is trying to delete the a user from its table but that user is referenced in another table (dbo.Invoices).

So you are seeing a foreign key constraint error where you are trying to delete a record who's primary key is referenced in another table as a foreign key.

Is the GeneratedById on the invoices table nullable? If it is then set the cascade rules up in Nhibernate to null out the GeneratedById when the parent entity, user, is deleted.

However, a common approach is to never fully delete any record and rather set a field on that entity to denote that its deleted, such as a field called IsDeleted (bit) or DeletedOn (datetime) and hide records that are "soft" deleted from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you all for give me suggestions.**

I have finally found a solution to my own problem.I just create a Rollback() the transaction method i.e."genRep.RollbackTransaction()" and create a new session(). Beacuse Nhibernate flush session after Flush().

Rollback method:

```
 public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        if (null != this._trans && this._trans.IsActive)
        {
            this._trans.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

and here is my code:

```
 catch (GenericADOException gae)
            {

                if (gae.InnerException.Message.IndexOf(referenceConstraint) != -1)
                {
                    genRep.RollbackTransaction();
                    genRep.NewSession();
                    UserWrapper userW = genRep.GetByIdUser(Convert.ToInt64(UserID));
                    userW.Status = UserStatus.PendingDelete;
                    genRep.Update(userW);

                 }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Error("Unexpected, unhandled exception: ", e);
            }
        }
```